# Position events below analog area in Highcharts combined line/timeline chart

Tags: highcharts, timeline

I have created a combined line/timeline chart in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t7x3L6wm/4/):

```js
// arbitrary code snippet required by stackoverflow editor:
      xAxis: [{
        type: 'datetime'
      }, {
        type: 'linear'
      }],
```

I would prefer the events to be positioned below the analog value grid rather than as currently, in the middle of it.

Is there any way to achieve this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can suggest two solutions:

- add a second yAxis and set heights for both y-axes:

  ```
   yAxis: [{
       height: '50%'
   }, {
       height: '50%',
       top: '50%'
   }],
  ```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/e0zhmyr7/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.height

- change the y values for x-range series in the current implementation

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ow1357tq/

Comment: Thank you. The first answer does precisely what I need.